# Snake-alike fluid layout algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm

The goal is to produce a fluid layout as show below.

[image]

So far I have a working function `moveBox(lastBox, "east")` that keeps track of the row and column indexes.

```js
function moveBox(box, where) {
  switch (where) {
    case "north":
      lastTopOffset -= BOX_HEIGHT + BOX_MARGIN;
      box.style.top  = lastTopOffset  + 'px';
      box.style.left = lastLeftOffset + 'px';
      rowIndex -= 1;
      break;
    //  ...    
  }
```

My [current code](http://jsfiddle.net/FTSZu/),

```js
(function () {
    var i, lastBox,
      MAX_DIVS       = 72,
      BOX_HEIGHT     = 50,
      BOX_WIDTH      = 100,
      BOX_MARGIN     = 5,
      field          = document.getElementById('fieldPerimeter'),
      fieldHeight    = field.offsetHeight,
      maxRows        = Math.floor(fieldHeight / (BOX_HEIGHT + BOX_MARGIN)),
      rowIndex       = 0,
      colIndex       = 0,
      lastLeftOffset = 0,
      lastTopOffset  = 0;

  function moveBox(box, where) {
    switch (where) {
      case "north":
        lastTopOffset -= BOX_HEIGHT + BOX_MARGIN;
        box.style.top  = lastTopOffset  + 'px';
        box.style.left = lastLeftOffset + 'px';
        rowIndex -= 1;
        break;

      case "east":
        lastLeftOffset += BOX_WIDTH + BOX_MARGIN;
        box.style.top  = lastTopOffset  + 'px';
        box.style.left = lastLeftOffset + 'px';
        colIndex += 1;
        break;

      case "south":
        lastTopOffset += BOX_HEIGHT + BOX_MARGIN;
        box.style.top  = lastTopOffset  + 'px';
        box.style.left = lastLeftOffset + 'px';
        rowIndex += 1;
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < MAX_DIVS; i += 1) {
    lastBox = document.createElement('div');
    lastBox.className = 'box';
    lastBox.innerHTML = i;
    field.appendChild(lastBox);      

    //delete me 
    if( (i + 1) % 2 === 0 || (i + 1)% 3 === 0){ 
      moveBox(lastBox, "east");
    } else {
      moveBox(lastBox, "south");
    }
    //delete me      

//    if(rowIndex < maxRows && rowIndex > 0){
//    if (colIndex % 4 === 0){
//      moveBox(lastBox, "south");
//    } else if (colIndex % 2 === 0){
//      moveBox(lastBox, "north");
//    } else {
//     moveBox(lastBox, "east");
//    }
//  } 

  }      
})();
```

appends divs to a container and then moves it.  The code below shows part of my attempts for specifing when to move North or South. But I'm struggling with achiving the desired layout.

```js
 if      (colIndex % 4 === 0) { moveBox(lastBox, "south"); } 
 else if (colIndex % 2 === 0) { moveBox(lastBox, "north"); }
 else                         { moveBox(lastBox, "east");  }
```

Comment: A fiddle, image demonstration, and code (thanks to Bart Kiers) on an interesting question from a new user? Upvote. I wish all new users had this going for them. `:)`

Comment: Is the way you've approached it a requirement, or just the one you've tried?

Comment: I've tried other approaches, I've posted it because I think I'm close but my head explodes trying to figure out the algorithm.  Later I want to use a random value for not going to the very North or South, but for now I just need some guiding with some pseudocode.  Thanks Mr. Kiers for the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Here is the working fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/zuY74/

*Note I hardcoded the `offsetHeight` in order to work on the fiddle and also added a `lastMove` variable at the top.*

```
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_DIVS; i += 1) {
    lastBox = document.createElement('div');
    lastBox.className = 'box';
    lastBox.innerHTML = i;
    field.appendChild(lastBox);

    if (i === 0) {
      rowIndex += 1;
    } else {
      if (colIndex % 4 === 0 && rowIndex < maxRows) {
        moveBox(lastBox, "south");
        lastMove = "south";
      } else if (colIndex % 2 === 0 && rowIndex !== 1 && lastMove !== "south") {
        moveBox(lastBox, "north");
        lastMove = "north";
      } else {
        moveBox(lastBox, "east");
        lastMove = "east";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Mr. Fortis

Answer (score 2):

The following works with grid positions rather than pixels, the idea being that you can convert a grid position to pixels without trouble.

My grid is pretty simple. The upper left is `(0, 0)`. So your box 0 is at `(0, 0)`, box 7 is at `(1, 6)`, etc.

If you have `maxrows` rows, then the first `maxrows-1` items go in `(0, 0)`, `(0, 1)`, etc. And item `maxrows` goes in `(1, maxrows-1)`. The next `maxrows-1` items go in `(maxrows-1,2)`, `(maxrows-2, 2)`, etc., and the item at `2*maxrows` goes in `(0, 3)`.

You should be able to compute an item's position in the grid from its number. Assume integer math here.

```
// xblock treats each two columns as a single entity.
xblock = itemNo / (maxrows + 1);
xpos = 2 * xblock;
ypos = itemNo % (maxrows + 1);
if (ypos == maxrows)
{
    // this is the last item, so we need to shift it.
    xpos += 1;
    ypos = maxrows - 1;
}

// Now, turn things upside down if xblock is odd
if ((xblock % 2) == 1 && ypos != maxrows)
{
    ypos = maxrows - ypos - 1;
}
```

At this point you have the grid position where the box should go. It should be a simple matter now to turn that grid position into pixels by multiplying the `xpos` by `BOX_WIDTH`, and adding the offset. Do the same thing for `ypos` and `BOX_HEIGHT`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that is a recurring pattern in the layout:
Starting from 0

- move box down 6 times (reach position 6)
- move box right 2 times (reach 8)
- move box up 6 times (reach 14)
- move box right 2 times (reach 16)
- repeat

-

```
var MOVES_DONE = 0;
var MOVES_LIMIT = 72;

/*
* First define the three movement functions that we will use 
* (right, down and left)
*/
function up(box) {
    console.log("up");
}

function down(box) {
    console.log("down");
}

function right(box) {
    console.log("right");
}

/*
*   Solution 1:
*   Starting from the top-left corner do the necessary moves to complete the 
*   layout:

          ---------------------------------
        |                                     |
         box,             up,   right,  right,
        down,             up,            start_over
        down,             up, 
        down,             up,
        down,             up,
        down,             up,       
        down,   right,   right, 
*/

var moves = [down, down, down, down, down, down, right, right,
             up, up, up, up, up, up, right, right];

var len_moves = moves.length;

while(MOVES_DONE < MOVES_LIMIT) {
    moves[MOVES_DONE % len_moves](box);
    MOVES_DONE ++;
}
```

Solution 2 using the same movement functions:

```
/**
*   Create a function that will apply a movement type to a box "times" times
*   For example move(down, 6)(box) will
*   move the box down 6 times if moves_done < moves_limit
*/
function move(move_type_function, times) {
    return function(box) {
        for (var i = 0; i < times, i + MOVES_DONE < MOVES_LIMIT; i++) {
            move_type_function(box);
      }
        return i;
   }
}

/**
* This is a complete cycle of the recurring pattern of the layout assuming that
* we are starting with the box positioned at the 
*/
var moves = [move(down, 6), move(right, 2), move(up, 6), move(right, 2)];

while(MOVES_DONE < MOVES_LIMIT) {
    MOVES_DONE += moves[MOVES_DONE % moves.length](box)
}
```

PS: I haven't really had time to test this in a browser so there might be some errors :)